# Why is my Spring Boot app with SQS Not Showing a JMSHealthIndicator?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-jms

I'm working on a Spring Boot application that takes messages from SQS as described on this post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-amazon-sqs-with-spring-boot-and-spring-jms/

When I access the built in Spring Boot health endpoint at `localhost:8081/health` I expect to see some information about the JMS broker as the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-health) say there are auto configured health indicators that are configured "when appropriate" one of which is the `JmsHealthIndicator`. Instead I just see the status and diskspace `{"status":"UP","diskSpace":{"status":"UP","total":31572619264,"free":24611381248,"threshold":10485760}}`

Does anyone know why we don't see anything about JMS on the health endpoint? The application works fine reading from SQS but since it's hosted in Kubernetes I want to add a readiness/liveness probe and to include JMS in the check.

For information our JMS config with `@EnableJms` is as follows

```
import javax.jms.Session;

import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.region.RegionProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsConfig.class);
private static final String LOWER_UPPER_CONCURRENCY = "3-10";

private final SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

public JmsConfig(RegionProvider regionProvider, AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
    this.connectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
            .withRegion(regionProvider.getRegion())
            .withAWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
            .build();
    LOGGER.info("Loading JmsConfig");
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
    factory.setConcurrency(LOWER_UPPER_CONCURRENCY);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate defaultJmsTemplate() {
    return new JmsTemplate(this.connectionFactory);
}

}
```

Then we also have a method annotated with `@JmsListener(destination = "${sqs.input.queue}")`

Edit: Note that I have already tried adding the following to the application.properties

```
management.health.defaults.enabled=true
management.health.jms.enabled=true
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
```

Thanks, 
Leanne.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that exposing the connection factory as a bean now results in a JMS section in the health response.

So by changing the code to this

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsConfig.class);
private static final String LOWER_UPPER_CONCURRENCY = "3-10";

public JmsConfig() {
    LOGGER.info("Loading JmsConfig");
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
    factory.setConcurrency(LOWER_UPPER_CONCURRENCY);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory(RegionProvider regionProvider, AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
    return SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
            .withRegion(regionProvider.getRegion())
            .withAWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate defaultJmsTemplate(SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
}

}
```

The health endpoint response looks like this

```
{
"status": "UP",
"jms": {
    "status": "UP",
    "provider": "Amazon"
},
"diskSpace": {
    "status": "UP",
    "total": 249779191808,
    "free": 165159432192,
    "threshold": 10485760
}
}
```

A colleague had a hunch after seeing the constructor for [JmsHealthIndicator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/JmsHealthIndicator.java) that the connection factory wasn't accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add a further property to your `application.properties` file:

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

According to the documentation:

> By default all sensitive HTTP endpoints are secured such that only
>   users that have an ACTUATOR role may access them. Security is enforced
>   using the standard HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole method
>
> If you are deploying applications behind a firewall, you may prefer
>   that all your actuator endpoints can be accessed without requiring
>   authentication. You can do this by changing the
>   management.security.enabled property

See more about this here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but we already had that set, it just wasn't something I included in this question. We have it working now so I'll post the answer :)